# ESP8266 flash memory has to be completely erased after every crash to be usable again

Tags: esp8266, platformio

I have an **ESP8266 D1 mini** on which I have written a program to fetch and display cryptocoin prices on a small OLED display. It uses libraries ESP8266WiFi, ESP8266HTTPClient, EEPROM, pgmspace, Wire, ArduinoJson, oled, and ESPAsyncWebServer. User configuration information is stored in EEPROM.

There's a problem in there somewhere which will cause the program to occasionally crash at a random time, perhaps after 30 or 40 hours of continuous operation.  When this happens, the processor reboots, begins running the *setup()* function, and then gives an exception(3). This reset/exception then occurs again, over and over, until power is removed from the device. If power is restored to the device, the same reset/exception sequence resumes, ad infinitum.

Reloading the program into the flash memory does not fix the problem. Even a simple Blink sketch will not run.  In fact, the only way I've found to make the device usable again is to use *esptool* to ***completely*** erase the flash memory, and then reload the program. This of course wipes out all of the user configuration information as well.

Analysis of the repeating exception shows this as the error:

```
LoadStoreError: Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store  epc1=0x40100ac8 in umm_malloc_core at /home/david/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif8266@3.20704.0/cores/esp8266/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.cpp:433
```

This has happened a couple dozen times so far, and I have lots of print statements that show the stack and heap sizes at various points in the program, none of which seem to provide any clues to the cause of the crash.  Unwinding the stack also makes no sense, as the exception decoder displays question marks for many of the program locations.  Close to the bottom of the stack is the call in my code that triggers the whole collapse - a *Print::println(__FlashStringHelper const*)* statement that works flawlessly until this crash occurs. Funny thing is, my program does not have a *println* statement at the location it shows in the crash analysis.

I imagine that, with enough effort, I can figure out what is causing the original crash that destroys the flash contents.  What I can't understand is how it borks it so badly that I can't even fix it by reloading the program - the entire flash must be erased before I can get the device working again. I have tried replacing the device, thinking it may be a hardware problem, but the new device also fails thusly.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess you upload with wrong setting of the flash size. try to set 'D1 min lite' for a Wemos with 1 MB flash. the normal D1 mini has 4 MB flash

Comment: Ok, I tried telling PlatformIO that it was a D1 mini lite, and I was able to reload the code and get it working again without fully erasing the flash. Thanks for the idea! Time will tell if it crashes again like before.   
But... this is not a D1 mini lite, it's an actual ESP8266 D1 mini.  There's still something amiss.  Plus, treating it as a D1 mini lite only allows me to use 1/4 of the flash available.

Comment: does it use an esp-12 module?

Comment: Yes, the ESP-12F.  This is the one I'm using: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B081PX9YFV/

Comment: "use 1/4 of the flash available" - did you use e.g. `esptool` to introspect your hardware to make sure you weren't sold fake chips (i.e. 1MB labelled as 4MB)?

Comment: Esptool reports 4MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was two issues: a 9-character buffer that I was copying text into that was 10 characters long (the old zero terminator thing), and I had mistakenly used send_p instead of send for sending the web page. Why these noobie errors caused this kind of behavior is beyond my comprehension, but two months after fixing those problems the error hasn't occurred again.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

This probably caused by heap fragmentation, Wherein holes are created every time there is a change in the variables size specially for String, until it will reached zero free memory:
[image]

---

**OBSERVATION**

you can monitor the FreeHeap using:

```
 Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
```

run it in the loop to observed the available memory.

---

**SOLUTION**

Call tcpCleanup regulary i the loop() function.

```
// do this before including other stuff like wificlient.h
#include "lwip/tcp_impl.h"

void tcpCleanup()
{
  while(tcp_tw_pcbs!=NULL)
  {
    tcp_abort(tcp_tw_pcbs);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great information, thank you for posting it. Great graphic too.  I'm a little dubious, however.  Wouldn't a reboot clear the heap and allow the program to run again? Even more so by reloading the program?

Comment: Another question is, how would clearing TCP network connections help?

Comment: @david, yes ESP restart will refresh the heap. You can monitor the heap then make necessary action before restarting.

Comment: then how could this be the problem? Erasing the flash and reloading the program is the only way I can get it to work again.

Comment: The problem is when heap memory shrinks, it will no longer handle other process which causes random reboot. random reboot may cause memory corruption specially when the code is performing save to memory.